# More than one submit button on a form

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.1, formtastic

I have a form that I am building in formtastic which is for more than one model.

This form is for one model with multiple nested models, but each section is separated using css and javascript, but I have a submit button on each section.

How can I modify the action for each of those buttons so that I can let the controller know which section the post is from (for redirection to the next section)

The basic solution I can think of is to have separate `semantic_form_for` tags going to the same action, with a different hidden field called `section`

Would it be the best way to approach this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to try [simple_form](https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form), which is a more current replacement for formtastic and is also fully compatible with Rails's own form helpers. You can then specify different commit names for each button, e.g.:

```
f.button :submit_section1

f.button :submit_section2
```

Comment: @JosephLeBrech if you look at the rendered HTML, you'll see that it says something like `<input name="..." commit="submit">`. It's the "commit" attribute that you control with the argument to the `button` method. That gets submitted to the server and you can use to distinguish buttons. Firebug taught me :-)